# Is there a way to manage Do Not Disturb settings on iOS with flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, do-not-disturb

There is a flutter package that can control Do Not Disturb settings in Android: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dnd.

I can't find any information on how to manage DND with iOS, for example programmatically turn it on or off in the app. Is this possible with iOS apps made in flutter, and if so how could this be done?

Comment: It isn't possible to manage DND on iOS from an app, regardless of what language you write in

Comment: OK -  thanks for confirming